# Changing <q> and </q> tags to " pairs in specific places

Tags: haskell, filter, pandoc

I am using a toolchain to convert markdown to HMTL5 using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) for insertion into WordPress's visual editor as HTML content.

When it comes to inserting images, WordPress puts what is called a `shortcode` of the form

```
[caption id="attachment_100" align="aligncenter" width="300" caption="This is an image caption"]
```

into the HTML text. This is not really markdown but is so interpreted by Pandoc which translates each `" ... "` pair into a `<q> ... </q>` pair for HTML output. This does not work correctly in WordPress.

I need to *prevent* the conversion of the `" ... "` but only those which occur within the well-defined `[caption ... ]` square brackets which are exclusively put in by WordPress and cannot be confused with other content that I put in.

I do not know enough about the [Pandoc API](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/doc/pandoc/) or [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) to write an inline paseser/filter to exempt this text fragment from Pandoc processing. The advice I have received on the pandoc mailing list has gone above my head so far, given my lack of acquaintance with Pandoc and Haskell.

I thought of writing a Perl filter but have been strongly dissuaded from using regexps for very good reason.

I am asking here to find out if there is a robust way to make the reverse substitution from `<q> ... </q>` tags to `" ... "` only for the text within the `[caption ... ]` block after it has been run through pandoc, as a post-processing step.

Can someone please suggest how I might go about this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

main = do
   inh  <- openFile "input.txt"  ReadMode
   outh <- openFile "output.txt" WriteMode
   str <- hGetContents inh
   hPutStrLn outh (outsideCaption str) 
   hClose inh
   hClose outh

outsideCaption::String->String
outsideCaption [] = []
outsideCaption str@(x:xs)
    | isPrefixOf "[caption" str = insideCaption str
    | otherwise                 = x:outsideCaption xs


insideCaption::String->String
insideCaption []       = []
insideCaption (']':xs) = ']':outsideCaption xs
insideCaption str@(x:xs)
    | (isPrefixOf "<q>"  str) = '\"':insideCaption (drop 3 str)
    | (isPrefixOf "</q>" str) = '\"':insideCaption (drop 4 str)
    |  otherwise              = x   :insideCaption         xs
```

This piece of code reads a file named "input.txt", does the substitution you described and prints the result to "output.txt".

replacing the current main with:

```
main = interact outsideCaption
```

makes it read from stdin to stdout, example:

```
[rothesay]Ygfijj: echo "testing <q> [caption<q></q>]" | ./test 
testing <q> [caption""]
```

Comment: Thank you. I compiled and ran it and it works! May I trouble you for two changes, though: (1) can it be made to run in place, writing to the same output file as the input, or otherwise accepting I/O from stdin and stdout? (2) I realize I need to strip a pair of `<p>` `</p>` tags as well. The first comes just before the leading `[caption` as `<p>[cation` and the second after the *second* `]` as `]</p>` rather than the after first enclosing `]`. Thanks again.

Comment: @chandra I added a suggestion for how to use stdin/stdout, could you povide a sample input/output for the other substitution you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for that. I trust that I can now read from and write to the same file. I am unable to enter sample I/O in the comments box. Please take a look at this [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/38is7n1bpie9h20/stackoverflow-comment.text).